# onTap() not working in ListWheelScrollView

Tags: flutter

I want to navigate to `InjectView` when one of the items is clicked on.
I wrapped each of the Container that are in the `ListWheelScrollView` with `InkWell()` but it is still not working.

Here is the code:

```
              Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                height: 300,
                width: 130,
                child: ListWheelScrollView(
                  itemExtent: 100,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  children: images
                      .map(
                        (e) => InkWell(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.2),
                            width: 130,
                            height: 90,
                            child: e,
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return InjectView(status: widget.status);
                                },
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                    )
```

I think the `ListWheelScrollView` is somehow shadowing it's containers?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38803

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is the listener not receiving the event? Is there an exception?

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad the `onTap` Method of the children of the `ListWheelScrollView` is not registering the taps.